# Removing Hover effect on specific tag

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the hover effect on my 'h3' tag *(lighter grey hover effect)*. It should still be link that is why i put it inside of my 'a' tag.

```css
.speakers a {
    color: var(--clr-grey);
}

.speakers a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-lgrey);
}
```

```html
<div class="speakers">
  <a href="#">
      <h3>Tessa Harmon</h3>
      Crafty Coding: Generating Knitting Patterns
  </a>
  <a href="#">
      <h3>Russ Unger</h3>
      From Muppets to Mastery: Core UX Principles from Mr. Jim Henson
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by hover effect? do you want to remove the pointer icon and use a default cursor icon?

Comment: which is the hover effect you want to 'remove' ? As far as i can see you are adding the same color on hover as on default state. Doesn't that work ?

Comment: use `cursor: default;` if you want to remove the pointer icon when link is hovered

Comment: @AmirSaleem I try to remove the color hover effect on my <h3> tag. it will become light grey if it hovers. but I don't want it to be applied on my h3 tag. tho I still want my h3 tag to be a link.

Comment: @MihaiT I am trying to remove the color hover effect on my <h3> tag. it will become light grey if it hovers. but I don't want it to be applied on my h3 tag. tho I still want my h3 tag to be a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then just overwrite the color of the `h3` when hovering `a`.
See bellow.

```css
.speakers a:hover {
color:blue; /* example purpose */
}

.speakers a {
    color: grey;
}


.speakers a:hover h3 {
  color: grey
  }
```

```html
<div class="speakers">
  <a href="#">
      <h3>Tessa Harmon</h3>
      Crafty Coding: Generating Knitting Patterns
  </a>
  <a href="#">
      <h3>Russ Unger</h3>
      From Muppets to Mastery: Core UX Principles from Mr. Jim Henson
  </a>
</div>
```